# Junit prerun call

Tags: java, junit

I am new to JUINT.  I am working on a system that runs through every Unit test in a project.  There are over one hundred of them.

What I need to do now is have a method called to set a condition prior to each JUNIT being called.  I would hate to have to edit each method by hand to add the condition

Comment: Would the `@Before` annotation solve your problem?

Comment: @MadcoreTom probably not since that would require writing a `@Before` in every test class.  (I assume OP has more than 1 since there are 100 tests)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a test suite that contains all your unit tests, and utilize the [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) annotation to run the common method once, before any of the tests are executed.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({MyTest1.class, MyTest2.class, MyTest3.class})
public class MyTestSuite {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        System.out.println("setting up");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 didn't realize you could `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` in a suite!

Comment: So, with this, the setup() will be run one time for each method in MyTestSuite?

Comment: @xarzu The `@BeforeClass` annotation ensures that the `setUp()` method is run only once for the entire test suite. The test suite itself can contain multiple unit test classes.

Comment: I think maybe you might also need import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;